# Vue.jsでVue3-Chartsを使って、添付画像のような積み上げ棒グラフを作成したい

Tags: vue.js

下記URLの「棒グラフの実装」をそのまま実装し、棒グラフの実装まではできました。
https://www.harubears.com/ja/tech-ja/vue3-charts-with-sample/

しかし、添付している画像のような積み上げ型の棒グラフの作成ができません。
公式サイトやGithubには実装可能だと書いてあるのですが、実装の仕方が詳細に書かれておらず困っている状況です。
既に「棒グラフの実装」まではできていますので、そこからの変更箇所を送っていただくか、もしくは例があればそちらを送っていただいても構いません。
お忙しいところ申し訳ありませんが、何卒ご協力お願いします。

【Vue3-charts公式サイト】
https://vue3charts.org

【GitHub】
https://github.com/ghalex/vue3-charts

[image: 添付画像]

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/leehe9qeydb861) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)